# window.scrollto and scrollIntoView not scroll smoothly in ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, frontend

I have a fixed top bar when I click it, the page will scroll to the corresponding part. However, it doesn't scroll smoothly in my iphone8(ios13), while it works perfectly in chrome and android.
I tried to use scrollIntoview, but it doesn't work either.
Here is the code

```
scrollToAnchor = tabIndex => {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: this.state.tabListTop[tabIndex] - 76,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in the old fashioned way:

```
smoothScroll = (height) => {
    // "height" is the Height you want to scroll to
    var i = 10;
    var int = setInterval(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, i);
        i += 10;
        if (i >= height ) clearInterval(int);
    }, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTo` does not support options in iOS Safari.
Here is the current status from CanIUse: https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollto